# how to write std_logic_vector output as unsigned in a file?

Tags: vhdl

The simulation results in Vivado are correct, and writing binary results to the file is also correct. However, when attempting to write decimal results to the file, “-” appears. I've noticed, it seems I can't use the write statement to write the unsigned numbers to the file , and also unable to convert them to strings directly for writing. I ended up choosing the integer option, but it seems to treat the most significant bit of the binary result as the sign bit. Can you please help me figure out how to avoid this error? I don't know how to correctly write the decimal results(without -) to the file.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;  
use std.textio.all;

entity example is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in STD_LOGIC;
           output : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0));
end example;

architecture Behavioral of example is
    signal fib_prev, fib_current : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0) := "00000000000000000000000000000001";
    file result_file : text open write_mode is "fibonacci_result.txt";
begin
    process (clk, reset)
        variable result_line : line; 
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            fib_prev <= "00000000000000000000000000000001";
            fib_current <= "00000000000000000000000000000001";
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            fib_current <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(fib_prev) + unsigned(fib_current));
            fib_prev <= fib_current;

            write(result_line, to_integer(unsigned(fib_current)));
            writeline(result_file, result_line);
        end if;
    end process;
    output <= fib_current; 
end Behavioral;
```

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;  
use std.textio.all;

entity example_tb is
end example_tb;

architecture testbench of example_tb is
    signal clk : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal reset : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal output : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);

    constant clock_period : time := 10 ns;  
begin
    uut: entity work.example
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            output => output
        );

    clk_process: process
    begin
        while now < 1000 ns loop  
            clk <= not clk;
            wait for clock_period / 2;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;

    stimulus_process: process
    begin
        reset <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        reset <= '0';
    wait;
    end process;
end testbench;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to so. I recommend you write a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You first example will write unsigned values to a file as your seen to want, what is the problem? The unsigned type is exactly that, unsigned and has no sign bit. The conversion to integer will only result in values from 0 upwards

Comment: when I use the first method, the first bit is the sign bit, leading to the "-" in the results.

Comment: I dont beleive you get a -ve result in the file - unsigned does not have a sign bit. Please post the whole code.

Comment: I don't understand why, after converting the result to an unsigned type and then to an integer, the most significant bit becomes the sign bit. The simulation results are correct, but only the results written to the document are incorrect. How can I send the complete code to you?

Comment: No one wants the complete code, here we're interested in a [mcve] producing the specific flagged error to aid future readers who might encounter the same problem. Here your declarations including the file declaration and context items (use clauses and library declarations) would illustrate the cause and an answer could demonstrate a solution. The purpose of Stackoverflow is to provide a reference database programming problems and their solutions. You'd simply be the first to benefit from a recognizable problem with an answer. Enough detail (specificity) and duplicates can be reduced.

Comment: In VHDL unsigned is a type declared in a package (e.g ieee.numeric_std) with a write procedure declared in a package. Usage of a writeline procedure would depend on the file type as well as the string value written to the buffer accessed with the access value (here) normal_line whose string array would specify the unsigned value being written by the write procedure. That's derailed somewhere in your unseen code. Without specifics answers are guesses and of reduced value to future readers.

Comment: I have re-edited the code, and now I'd like you to help me take a look why the results written to the document include “-”. Thank you

Comment: Your example code is not valid syntactically nor semantically containing sequential periods which are separators. You don't specify the expected value of normal_line.all. The to_integer function would result in selecting a write procedure by overload resolution with a profile of write[line, integer] where the string value appended to the line object would have a string format prefixed by '-' or a '+'. You could write the std_logic_vector value itself, textually indistinguishable from numeric_std.unsigned using std_logic_textio.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-1993 14.3 Package TEXTIO "-- The representation of both INTEGER and REAL values is that of a decimal literal (see 13.4.1 ), with the addition of an optional leading sign. The sign is never written if the value is nonnegative."  "Each WRITE procedure similarly appends data to the end of the string value designated by parameter L;", "The format of the appended data is defined by the string representations defined above for the READ procedures." You haven't assigned a value to output_tb, it should be all 'U's which should get a warning from to_integer which should also return 0.

Comment: Your above code without the ........ simulates and produces an output.txt file with 500 0 values without minus signs, each on a eparate line without any other modifications. What VHDL implementation and what version? Or does the code fail to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Are you referring to the Vivado version I'm using? It seems to be 2022.2. The entire project is generates two Fibonacci sequences, with one of them randomly generating some abnormal values. I want to save the results of both sequences in two separate files.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Do you mean that if I use to_integer in the write statement, it won't work even if I've previously converted std_logic_vector to unsigned?

Comment: There is no problem writing integers to a file. On your case, the values written to a file will be 0 or greater. If you are getting -ve values, then I suggest you are looking at the wrong file. If the value is greater than 2**31-1, an error should occur, as vivado simulator only uses 32 bit integers. If a -ve value is printed, then vivado has a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried writing the results directly to the document, those binary results are correct, but only when I want to write decimal it gives "-".Are there any other ideas to avoid this mistake?

Comment: Your question still lacks a [mre] that shows the behavior. Please [edit] your question and provide it.

Comment: I made some modifications to it. Could you please take a look and let me know if there are any unclear parts

Comment: We still cannot see the UUT. You would not even need it if you create a proper [mre], because according to you the issue is in the conversions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I pasted the original code, which is the Top module of the project. It has many sub-modules, but the simulation output for the whole project and the simulation tests for these sub-modules are all normal. As you said, the main issue is in the final step of writing to the file.

Comment: I'm afraid you do not yet understand "complete" in [mre]. Actually we are not interested in your Fibonacci implementation, as I wrote in my former comment. Please invest some minutes (instead of multiple of us) to provide an example of a value that is written with a minus sign.

Comment: I submitted the part that caused problems this time. Could you check if it is correct?

Comment: If I run your example, it warns me. "_NUMERIC_STD.TO_INTEGER: metavalue detected, returning 0_" and the output file contains only 5 lines of zero. Do you see the problem? Provide a [mre] that shows the minus sign, else we cannot help you.

Comment: I apologize for not testing it separately yesterday. This time, I created a new project and tested them in Vivado. I think you can run it this time and you will notice that the simulation results do not have a negative sign. However, in the documentation, the results still include a negative sign.

Answer (score 0):

These are the two lines of importance from your code:

signal fib_prev, fib_current : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
write(result_line, to_integer(unsigned(fib_current)));

your trouble is that vhdl integer is only 32 bits wide, so bit 31 is always a sign. you need to convert your bit vector into decimal number yourself, perhaps writing a function for it, here is a recipe:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble

will let you convert your 32 bit binary number into BCD format (you will need 40 bits for that).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it helped me resolve my issue.